# How can I make a flexbox layout with two rows, but with items grouped into two sub-columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It's hard to explain this with words.
I'm trying to do a list that looks like this using flexbox:
[image]

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
  width: 200px; height: 140px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
 /*?*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it's hard to answer this with just words. We need code. what's your HTML structure for example. What have you tried ?

Comment: A simple ul with multiple li inside. I'm going to edit.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yLh97wcv/7/ here's a way to do it, but as @MihaiT said it's hard to answer this question this way.

Comment: Yes sorry. I've just added a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `order` and some `nth-child` selectors.

To select every 2 elements ( your 3-4, 7-8 elements ) you can use `li:nth-child(4n), li:nth-child(4n-1)`. For example if n=1 then you would select `4*1` and `4*1-1`. So the 4th and 3rd element. And so on.

To select the other elements ( not necessary in your example but it's good to know ) , you use `li:nth-child(4n-2),li:nth-child(4n-3)`

Then, you change their order inside the flex container by setting `order:1` . Default was 0. Read more here -> [flex order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property)

See snippet below

```css
li:nth-child(4n),
li:nth-child(4n-1) {
  background: Red;
  order: 1;
}

li:nth-child(4n-2),
li:nth-child(4n-3) {
  background: blue;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: 140px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

*OBS* i used `width: calc(25% - 10px);` on `li` because `200px x 4` was exceeding the width of the SO snippet :)

Comment: Ok thanks ! I knew this had something to do with order. Is there any way to make this work with a variable number of children ?

Comment: well it works with any number of children. 2 stay on top, next 2 below, 2 on top, next 2 below and so on

Comment: Ok I just have to modify flex-basis according to the number of children in the list to stick with two rows ! Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

```css
ul {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
list-style-type: none;
width: 450px;
}

li {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
color: white;
font-size: 34px;
height: 70px;
width: 100px;
margin: 3px;
background: dodgerblue;
border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
   
 </ul>
```

Comment: I downvoted because as you can see, the OP wants 3-4 and 7-8 elements to be under 1-2 and respectively 5-6 elements. With your code you are just putting the elements in their default order.

Comment: My bad i did not even notice there was a different order to the box numbers!